# Comparing two variable that are number

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried it this way but it isn't working i don't know what is the issue

```
<input type="button" class="bt" value="Click me">

$('.bt').click(function(){
  if(parseInt($('.qt').val()) >= 1 || parseInt($('.qt').val()) <= 99)
  {
      alert('Its smallert');
  }
  else if(parseInt($('.qt').val()) >= 100 || parseInt($('.qt').val()) <= 200)
  {
      alert('Its greater');
  }
});
```

Comment: check the browser console for some error and tell here

Comment: `it isn't working` isn't a proper problem statement

Comment: what type of object is 'qt' ?

Comment: Where is `.qt` element in your code?

Comment: what error do you get in browser console? do you load jquery before your script?

Comment: Not working in the scene `syntax error`? or `logical error` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it to an and (`&&`):

```
if(parseInt($('.qt').val()) >= 1 && parseInt($('.qt').val()) <= 99)
{
   alert('Its smallert');
}
else if(parseInt($('.qt').val()) >= 100 && parseInt($('.qt').val()) <= 200)
{
   alert('Its greater');
}
```

Other wise the second statement is never hit: 100 is greater than 1 so the first statement using or (`||`)would be true

Answer (score 0):

Your code always go into the first condition, never into `else` branch because each number is `higher than 1 OR lower than 99`.

Use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
if(parseInt($('.qt').val()) >= 1 && parseInt($('.qt').val()) <= 99) {
    alert('Its smallert');
} else if (parseInt($('.qt').val()) >= 100 && parseInt($('.qt').val()) <= 200) {
    alert('Its greater');
}
```

Better code, the same function. Little bit faster and more readable:

```
var val = parseInt($('.qt').val());

if (val >= 1 && val <= 99) {
    alert('Its smallert');
} else if (val >= 100 && val <= 200) {
    alert('Its greater');
}
```